# XSL replace attribute inside richtext

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, xml-attribute

I would like to change the content of a xml node.
This is my source:

```
<content>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
        <a href="http://www.example.com">
            <strong>http://www.example.com</strong>
        </a>
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
   </p>
</content>
```

I would like to change the part inside the -Tag to the following result:

```
<content>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
                        <a xlink:show="new" xlink:href="http://www.example.com" xlink:type="simple">
                            <strong>http://www.example.com</strong>
                        </a>
                        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
                    </p>
            </content>
```

So, basically I want to change "href" to xlik:href. Everything else should stay untouched, like the

-tag or the -Tag.

I was hoping I can do something like this:

```
    <xsl:for-each select=".../content">    

....
....

    <xsl:variable name="content">
            <xsl:copy-of select="content/node()" />
        </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="replace($content, 'href', 'xlink:href')" />

....
....

    <xsl:for-each/>
```

But the result is, that all tags and attributes where gone:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
>   nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
>   sed diam voluptua.
>
> ```
>                       http://www.example.com
>
>                   At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea >rebum.
> ```

What can I do to change only the href-Attribute?

Comment: Looks like you just need to add the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start off with the Identity Template

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then have a template that matches the `a` element, that creates a new `a` element with the attributes you need.

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <a xlink:show="new" xlink:href="{@href}" xlink:type="simple">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='href']|node()"/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes you have the `xlink` namespace prefix defined in the XSLT.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <a xlink:show="new" xlink:href="{@href}" xlink:type="simple">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='href']|node()"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: In answer to your comment, you don't really need an `xsl:for-each` here, unless you are actually doing other transformations other than just changing the `href` attribute. The template approach is usually the way to go, and definitely worth learning out. But if it helps, here is a stylesheet that uses `xsl:for-each` that you may be able to adapt to suit your needs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="content">
    ...
    <content>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </content>
    ...
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <a xlink:show="new" xlink:href="{@href}" xlink:type="simple">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='href']|node()"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This looks very promising. But let me guess, I can't use this inside a xsl:for-each?

Comment: You can do an `<xsl:apply-templates />` within an `xsl:for-each` for example. It may help if you edited you question of your XSLT that contains the `xsl:for-each` you are trying to adapt. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, forget about that. I know that programming in templates seems to be much better, but I am not very used to that type of programming.

Comment: It is worth making an effort to learn about templates in XSLT as they are really what XSLT is based on. If it helps though, I have amended my answer to show it using `xsl:for-each` (although it isn't really necessary if you are just changing one thing and nothing else)

Comment: Awesome, thx a lot. I definitely will try to understand and learn how to use temlates.